# Do modal calculi work with possible worlds?

Tags: modal-logic

I use a natural deduction calculus for modal propositional logic, but my question eventually is about any (sound) modal calculi with/without axioms.

Just as an example take a proof like $\square$A $\vdash$ A that any calculus based on T or stronger can prove.

Now, $\square$A $\vdash$ A looks like a false proof because in modal logic you just cannot conclude from some $\square$A to some A independent from the world they are in, but only if they play both in the same world. So are proofs like $\square$A $\vdash$ A just a short-cut for $w_{i}\square$A $\vdash$ $w_{i}$A, i.e. in your mind you always have to add $w_{i}$ before any wff?

Comment: See [Possible Worlds Semantics for Modal Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/)

Comment: But my question concerns not the semantics but the syntactics. Again, I want to know how a proof $\square$A $\vdash$ A ought to be read: like I suggest with reference to an arbitrary but fixed world $w_{i}$ or not; but then as I wrote I‘d find it irritating because $\square$A $\vdash$ A cannot mean that from any $\square$A you can conclude A because e.g. when $\square$A is true in world w1 then A could still be false in w2 (assuming a T-model for instance).

Comment: Syntactical prrof means axioms+rules.

Comment: I think I got it myself. In a modal calculus A $\vdash$ B (A, B are wff of a modal logic language) does not care about worlds, it just means that B follows from A, period. If the modal calculus wants to be sound it must also hold A $\vDash$ B and because of the possible world semantics that automatically translates into A,w $\vDash$ B,w.